# How to reduce the number of Power BI request to database by preventing real-time filtering functionality

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, powerbi

I'm currently working on MS Power Bi report. However, I have got a problem that I using visualisation tool filter, which makes too many requests to update report page.

In comparison to SSRS with Power BI, by using SSRS end users select the parameters first, then send the request to sql server. However, Power bi sends requests to sql server in real-time.

Is there any way to stop the real time functionality by using Power BI?

Comment: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/tag/cache-management/

Comment: It's a good article by still, basically, We need our end users select the parameters first, then make the request to sql server and execute the query like the SSRS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "query reduction" and worked since November 17 update of Power BI Desktop.

> To access these options, go to the Options dialog under File > Options
>   and settings > Options, and select Query reduction.

See [there](https://workingondata.wordpress.com/2017/11/08/power-bi-desktop-query-reduction-for-direct-query-models/) and [there](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-november-2017-feature-summary/#slowDataSource)